# Correlation Of dynamic value in Gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, correlation, gatling

I'm trying to correlate or create a "Check" in Gatling load tool, but not sure how to do it. I Went through the advanced tutorial doc from official Gatling website but couldn't exactly find much on correlation of the dynamic value.

Below is the peice of code from my script

```
.feed(feeder)

    .exec(http("EnterDetails")
        .post("/events/review.action")
        .headers(headers_6)
        .formParam("userInfo.spgEmail", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.title", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.firstName", "${FirstName}")
        .formParam("userInfo.lastName", "${LastName}")
        .formParam("userInfo.address1", "Open")
        .formParam("userInfo.address2", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.city", "${City}")
        .formParam("userInfo.state", "NYY")
        .formParam("userInfo.country", "US")
        .formParam("userInfo.zipCode", "10016")
        .formParam("userInfo.primaryNoInfo.optedIn", "false")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneTwoInfo.optedIn", "false")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneThreeInfo.optedIn", "false")
        .formParam("userInfo.primaryNoInfo.validInd", "Y")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneTwoInfo.validInd", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneThreeInfo.validInd", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneUseType1", "0")
        .formParam("userInfo.primaryNoInfo.phoneNumber", "9876543211")
        .formParam("userInfo.primaryNoInfo.extension", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.country1", "US%28%2B1%29")
        .formParam("__checkbox_userInfo.primaryNoInfo.oneTimeOptInPresent", "true")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneUseType2", "-1")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneTwoInfo.phoneNumber", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneTwoInfo.extension", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.country2", "US%28%2B1%29")
        .formParam("__checkbox_userInfo.phoneTwoInfo.oneTimeOptInPresent", "true")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneUseType3", "-1")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneThreeInfo.phoneNumber", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.phoneThreeInfo.extension", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.country3", "US%28%2B1%29")
        .formParam("__checkbox_userInfo.phoneThreeInfo.oneTimeOptInPresent", "true")
        .formParam("userInfo.email", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.retypeEmail", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.nonCCPayment", "true")
        .formParam("userInfo.SPGNumber", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.arrivalCarrier", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.transportationNumber", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.transportationArrTime", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.hotelArrivalTime", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.hotelDepartureTime", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.SRequest", "")
        .formParam("userInfo.IAgree", "true")
        .formParam("__checkbox_userInfo.IAgree", "true")
        .formParam("method%3Aexecute", "Review+Your+Reservation+"))
    .pause(2)
    .exec(http("ReviewREservation")
        .get(uri3 + "/s01000706679492?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=21%2F3%2F2016%2012%3A45%3A54%204%200&D=D%3D&fid=31A8BC73D5B8ACEB-2B64CD0ACE185774&ce=UTF-8&pageName=Review%20Reservation&g=https%3A%2F%2Fstg.starwoodmeeting.com%2Fevents%2Freview.action&r=https%3A%2F%2Fstg.starwoodmeeting.com%2Fevents%2Fselectcreate%21execute.action%3FselRoom%3D1&cc=USD&ch=StarGroups&server=StarGroups&c2=SOCIAL&c3=1603295001&c4=271&c5=SI&c6=YES&c8=en&s=1600x838&c=24&j=1.6&v=N&k=Y&bw=1042&bh=733&AQE=1")
        .headers(headers_3))
    .pause(7)
    .exec(http("request_13")
        .post("/events/confirm.action")
        .headers(headers_6)
        .formParam("method%3Aexecute", "Complete+Your+Reservation"))
    .pause(4)

    .exec(http("CompleteReservation")
        .get(uri3 + "/s03623649917832?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=21%2F3%2F2016%2012%3A46%3A5%204%200&D=D%3D&fid=31A8BC73D5B8ACEB-2B64CD0ACE185774&ce=UTF-8&pageName=Reservation%20Confirmation&g=https%3A%2F%2Fstg.starwoodmeeting.com%2Fevents%2Fconfirm.action&r=https%3A%2F%2Fstg.starwoodmeeting.com%2Fevents%2Freview.action&cc=CAD&purchaseID=20160421_734091125&ch=StarGroups&server=StarGroups&events=purchase&products=%3B271%3B1%3B100.00&c2=SOCIAL&c3=1603295001&c4=271&v4=20160421_734091125&c5=SI&c6=YES&c8=en&s=1600x838&c=24&j=1.6&v=N&k=Y&bw=1042&bh=733&AQE=1")
        .headers(headers_3))

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

In The above code I have a dynamic Purchase ID in

**.exec(http("CompleteReservation")**
which gets generated from the server and needs to be correlated.

From The Gatling Documentation, I understand( correct me if I'm wrong) that we need the inspect element code to get the CSS path.(Shown Here).
[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD3wM.png)

Please let me know how do we correlate .TIA.

Comment: Any answers please :(

Comment: First of all your link "Inspect Element" is wrong. Next, please specify what does it mean "needs to be correlated" .. do you mean that it needs to be read from response? If so, how the response looks like? Basically specify what you want to do with it.

Comment: OK, in simple terms, how do we correlate the dynamic value in Gatling.For Ex:- in Load runner , we take the LB and RB from the response and correlate it but in Gatling, where do we see the response and how do we correlate the dynamic value.

Answer (score 1):

In Gatling you have to use checks to extract a value from response. Take a look in [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.0/http/http_check.html#http-response-body).

You can choose to use `regex` or `xpath` to extract value in tag. But in your case I'd recommend to use simple `regex` because IMO in your example response there are not tags or IDs where you can easily hook with `xpath`. I mean the way that the `xpath` expression will still remain simple and understandable. Next thing is to extract value into session and afterwards to use it.

Following is the example scenario extracting query path of URI from response received from `example.com` which is afterwards printed in console:

```
val scn = scenario("Checks")
  .exec(
     http("root")
    .get("/")
    .check(
      // Extracting URI query path from response body via regexp and storing into session
      regex("""www\.iana\.org/([a-z/]*)""").find.saveAs("queryPath")
    )
  )
  // Printing the value from session
  // Important thing to note is how you can access stored value from session
  .exec { session =>
    println(" QUERY PATH --> " + session("queryPath").as[String])
    session
  }
```

In your case your last part could look something like this:

```
.exec(http("CompleteReservation")
    .get(uri3 + "/s03623649917832?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=21%2F3%2F2016%2012%3A46%3A5%204%200&D=D%3D&fid=31A8BC73D5B8ACEB-2B64CD0ACE185774&ce=UTF-8&pageName=Reservation%20Confirmation&g=https%3A%2F%2Fstg.starwoodmeeting.com%2Fevents%2Fconfirm.action&r=https%3A%2F%2Fstg.starwoodmeeting.com%2Fevents%2Freview.action&cc=CAD&purchaseID=20160421_734091125&ch=StarGroups&server=StarGroups&events=purchase&products=%3B271%3B1%3B100.00&c2=SOCIAL&c3=1603295001&c4=271&v4=20160421_734091125&c5=SI&c6=YES&c8=en&s=1600x838&c=24&j=1.6&v=N&k=Y&bw=1042&bh=733&AQE=1")
    .headers(headers_3))
    .check(
        regex("""Your confirmation number is (\d+)""") // Regular expression with group which represents confirmation number.
       .find
       .saveAs("confirmationNumber") // Now the extracted regexp group is stored in session under "confirmationNumber" as name.
    )
    // Missing, check, transformation or use of value from session
```

I don't know your usage of extracted value thus it's missing in snippet above . But I hope that you will already have an idea how to handle responses and how to use the extracted values next.

I hope that it helps.